# How to publish a Console Application that uses 3rd party references?

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-2015, console-application, publish, npgsql

My problem might seem specific, but in fact it is probably very general: How to publish a Console Application that uses 3rd party references?

I am using Visual Studio 2015 to make a Console Application called Gdx2PostgreSql programmed in Visual Basic. The application is reading data in a Gdx-file (output from a GAMS program, www.gams.com) and writing the data to a PostgreSql database. The interface to PostgreSql is handled by NpgSql, www.npgsql.org. NpgSql is referenced as

```
\\dtu-storage\hela\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GDX to PostgreSQL 2\packages\Npgsql.3.1.7\lib\net451\Npgsql.dll
```

The program functions correctly when it is executed in Debug mode inside Visual Studio.

I have to be able to run the program from the command prompt in a CMD window. Moreover, I have to be able to run the program by spawning from a GAMS program using the GAMS syntax

```
Execute 'Gdx2PostgreSql "FileName.gdx" "CaseName"';
```

I have published the program and run the setup file installing the program. But when I run it in a CMD window I get the error:

```
'Gdx2PostgreSql' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I get the same error message when spawning from my GAMS program.

Being rather desperate I have tried renaming the file setup.exe in the Publish-folder to Gdx2PostgreSql.exe. When I use this file I get:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Npgsql, Version=3.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

That is, NpgSql is not known to the program.

As I see it, I need to have one EXE-file that holds all what is needed - especially because my program should be able to run on other PCs, too.

Can anyone help me make my program Gdx2PostgreSql function?

Finally, I should mention that I have made other programs reading Gdx-files and using NggSql to write to PostgreSql. These programs function correctly, but they are Windows Forms Applications – and not Console Applications.

Comment: There are two things I'd check, first of all when you click on the Npgsql.dll in the solution explorer, in the properties window try setting copy local to true.  Also if it does run in debug mode then you should literally be able to navigate to YourConsoleApp/bin/debug .  You should be able to copy and paste those files anywhere else and run the .exe just fine.

Comment: @D.Mac
Npgsql.dll had Local=True.
I have copied Gdx2PostgreSql.exe and Npgsql.dll from bin/Release to the folder where GAMS is installed. (That is, I am not 'publishing' the program.) Then it seems to function when called from a GAMS program.

Answer (score 0):

Console applications aren't really any different from winforms applications - you have to distribute the EXE along with any DLLs it depends on - in the same directory. As mentioned in the comment, after building your program you should be able to find everything you need under bin/Debug (or Release).

Regarding why your `Gdx2PostgreSql` isn't being found, that's likely a problem of path - try running your program with an absolute path, or cd'ing into bin/Debug (or Release) before executing it.

Comment: I have copied Gdx2PostgreSql.exe and Npgsql.dll from bin/Release to the folder where GAMS is installed. (That is, I am not 'publishing' the program.) Then it seems to function when called from a GAMS program.